# S#arp Architecture Visual Studio 2010 Beta 1 Template

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, s#arp-architecture

How do I make S#arp Architecture project template work with Visual Studio 2010 Beta 1?

Does anyone have an updated template or a converter? I've put it in all the places possible, but Visual Studio still doesn't pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, it'll need a version bump. It's possible this is all it needs. Open up the xml file in your favourite text editor and you should be able to work out what to edit.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, changed a few things, but it didn't help. I've compared the file with some other preinstalled templates, but they are a bit different.